# Definition of Taylor Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying the Vector Calculus of Susan Colley, in particular, Taylor Theorem, its definition says:

$p_k(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2}(x-a)^2 + ... + \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}$

I'm fine with this definition, the problem is here:

$f(x) = p_k(x) + R_k(x,a)$

What does mean this remainder? $R_k(x,a)$ and why $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{R_k(x,a)}{(x-a)^k}\to0$

Comment: The **definition** of the remainder is $R_k(x;a):=f(x)=P_{k,a}(x)$. The remainder (as the name suggests) is the difference between the actual $f(x)$ and the approximation $P_{k,a}(x)$. The fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{R_k(x;a)}{(x-a)^k}=0$ is the **conclusion** of (one version of) Taylor's theorem, so to answer the "why", you have to look at the proof of the theorem

Comment: What do you mean by the definition on Taylor theorem? It's statement? Note that since you have $f(x) = p_k(x) + R_k(x,a)$ and you know $f,p_k$ are then $R_k(x,a)$ is simply their difference....The reason why $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{R_k(x,a)}{(x-a)^k}\to0$ is because this is exactly what the Theorem prooves, this follows from the Lagrange form of the remainder.